# ContextSwitchDeadLock after changing ListViewItem property from another Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I am struggling with this for a whole day now.

This is how I start my thread

```
new Thread(() => MyFunction()).Start();
```

MyFunction() ends with this piece of code to update a GUI's listview:

```
Utilities.MainForm.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    Utilities.MainForm.UpdateSearches();
}));
```

I have also tried `BeginInvoke`.

Utilities.MainForm is set to `this` in my MainForm's constructor. It's a static property of Utilities I use to get the current instance of my form.

In UpdateSearches() I retrieve the new data from my database and refill the listview like so

```
lstSearches.Items.Clear();
lstSearches.Items.AddRange((ListViewItem[])listItems.ToArray(typeof(ListViewItem)));
```

All the more I am surprised that the next action leads to a crash (ContextSwitchDeadLock).

```
if (selectedIndex >= 0 && lstSearches.Items.Count > selectedIndex)
{
    lstSearches.Items[selectedIndex].Selected = true;
    //lstSearches.Select();
}
```

selectedIndex means the index in lstSearches that was selected previously and the index DOES exist, I checked that. You can even set the index to 0, like

```
lstSearches.Items[selectedIndex].Selected = true;
```

and this line will always crash my application, **when called through Invoke**.
If you put a return before this, things work, else the whole GUI freezes etc. Once I put `Debugger.Break()` before it and changed the Selected property to true in Visual Studio (I hope you know what I mean, it's when you hover an object and a window opens and you can see and set properties/ methods). In the moment I changed false to true and pressed enter - the same happened, everything freezes and finally I get a ContextSwitchDeadLock.

This only happens when called from my invoke construction but oddly enough there are no problems with manipulating form controls in the code above.

Comment: Basically what you want is execute task on the background without freeze the GUI, right?

Comment: no no I just want to select an item in my listview from another thread without my application to crash